Connection between Liouville's formula and stability of linear systems
In my university textbook I have a statement:
For a linear differential system $\frac{dx}{dt}=A(t)*x$ to be stable is necessary that $\int_{0}^{t} SpA(\tau)d\tau <= M$,
where $M$ is a constant, $SpA$ is trace of matrix $A$ and $X(t)$ is fundamental matrix
It is said that it's easy to get from Liouville's formula.
However, I don't really understand how to get it. Could somebody please explain? Thanks in advance.
